# How can i change default port 80 and 443 in esxi host 6.7?

Tags: port, esxi

I m running an esxi 6.7 free.

I would like to expose my esxi to internet through my router. But i want to change the default port whose are 80 and 443.

I found many tutorials / knownledge base available for esxi 5.0 and 6.0 but none of theses are working.

In theses tutorial, there are part with firewall and reverse proxy but no matter what i do, nothings works, mostly when i restart the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's already solved but for others....

How to change port by ssh on ESXi 6.7 host video ->
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7kuwmLuwvU
or set in router port redirecting from 443 to desired port if possible.

edit:
for the ones they prefer to read :-)

```
1. enable ssh on esxi host
2. connect via ssh or press alt + f1 on esxi host
3. edit this file by command vi /etc/vmware/rhttpproxy/config.xml
4. find text https by command :/https
<!-- HTTPS port to be used by the reverse proxy -->
<httpsPort>443</httpsPort>
5. change port to eg. 9443 
(press insert before editing and after finished press esc save it by :wq)
6. reboot needed by command reboot
7. after reboot connect to ssh and create new file changedport.xml by command 
vi /etc/vmware/firewall/changedport.xml
8. copy this text to console.
<ConfigRoot>
  <service>
    <id>changedport</id>
    <rule id='0000'>
      <direction>inbound</direction>
      <protocol>tcp</protocol>
      <porttype>dst</porttype>
      <port>9443</port>
    </rule>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <required>false</required>
  </service>
</ConfigRoot>
9. save it by :wq
10. refresh firewall rules by command esxcli network firewall refresh
```

This is not a permanent solution.
After restarting, you need to add firewall rules again
and execute command esxcli network firewall refresh

Comment: Could you just describe how to do it instead of just posting a YouTube link?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.

As you described it's not a permanent solution.

To make it permanent you need to do the same but save it inside a VIB file as described here:

https://www.altaro.com/vmware/how-to-create-persistent-firewall-rules-on-esxi/#comment-18186

Following this guide i've created my own custom vib that allows port 444

You can download it here: https://multifilemirror.com/hik1l28cf6du/firewall444.vib.html

This VIB file is a simple archive so you can just unpack it multiples times to see the xml files inside to verify it's only this and there are no other malicious additional settings.

Just upload the VIB file to the ESXI server and run 'esxcli software vib install' command to install it with SSH

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. edit "/etc/vmware/rhttpproxy/config.xml" (`<httpsPort>443</httpsPort>`  to `<httpsPort>4444</httpsPort>`)
2. run command "/etc/init.d/rhttpproxy restart"
3. create new file "/etc/vmware/firewall/changes.xml"
4. copy this text to file:

> ```
> <ConfigRoot>
>     <service>
>         <id>changedport</id>
>         <rule id='0000'>
>             <direction>inbound</direction>
>             <protocol>tcp</protocol>
>             <porttype>dst</porttype>
>             <port>4444</port>
>         </rule>
>         <enabled>true</enabled>
>         <required>false</required>
>     </service>
> </ConfigRoot>
> ```

5. run command "/sbin/esxcli network firewall refresh"
6. copy above file into /vmfs/volumes/xxxxxxx-80925220-52bf-b8ac6f41950b/changes.xml
7. add below code to "/etc/rc.local.d/local.sh" for work after reboot:

> ```
> /sbin/cp /vmfs/volumes/xxxxxxx-80925220-52bf-b8ac6f41950b/changes.xml/ etc/vmware/firewall/
>
> /sbin/esxcli network firewall refresh
>
> exit 0
> ```

done.